# How can I handle the error that socket.error: [Errno 10060]

Tags: sockets, python-2.7

I'd like to handle the error when it occurs. So I googled it and got an answer using 'try' and 'except'. But the problem happens when I'm using following codes.

```
uri = sys.argv[1]
urlLst = uri.split("/")
uriRequest = uri.replace(urlLst[0],'')
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(urlLst[0])
conn.request("GET",uriRequest)
respon1 = conn.getresponse()
```

This code returns the error below.

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed becau....
```

And then, I added 'try' and 'except'.

```
uri = sys.argv[1]
urlLst = uri.split("/")
uriRequest = uri.replace(urlLst[0],'')
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(urlLst[0])
conn.request("GET",uriRequest)
try :
    respon1 = conn.getresponse()
except socket.error:
    print "You got Error!!"
```

Of coursely they didn't get through. How can I handle this error when it occurs?
Additionally, let me know if you don't understand my poor english fully.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in `conn.request()`, thus you have to put the call into the `try` block:

```
try:
    conn.request("GET", uriRequest)
    respon1 = conn.getresponse()
except socket.error:
    print "You got Error!"
```